# How does SAS macro quoting interact with format literals?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Executing locally in a clean session:

```
%let x = %str(put(age, best.));

proc sql;
    select &x from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

This generates the following error:

```
1     put(age, best.)
               ----
               22
                ----
                76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a format name, ?.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

But this "manually-resolved" version runs without notes, warnings or errors:

```
proc sql;
    select put(age, best.) from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

Can somebody explain exactly what %str() is doing in this program that causes an issue at execution time? Apologies for the vague question, but I am unsure what the relevant interactions are; I cannot replicate using equivalent data-step syntax so perhaps proc SQL peculiarities are involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered at [this question on runsubmit.com](http://www.runsubmit.com/questions/601/how-does-sas-macro-quoting-interact-with-proc-sql-and-format-literals):

> I'm going to mark this answer as
>   correct because it led me to this page
>   of documentation:
>   http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#tw3514-unquote.htm
>   - "In rare cases, masking text with a macro quoting function changes the way
>   the word scanner tokenizes the text
>   ... The word scanner does not use it
>   as the boundary of a literal token in
>   the input stack". Sounds like a bug,
>   frankly, but if the tokenizer
>   algorithm is as ancient and hairy as I
>   imagine, I'd spin it as a quirk too!

Answer (score 3):

The %str() function masks a character string during macro compilation. Remove the %str() function in the let statement or add an %unquote() function in the sql select to have if resolve correctly.

Comment: But why would masking a character string during macro compilation cause this error? I would expect all macro quoting to be resolved by the time the code is executed.

Comment: The %str masks strings during compilation while its sibling %quote masks strings during execution. It's something in the combination of proc sql, macro compilation and execution. This paper explains a lot about macro quoting: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi28/011-28.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a format statement instead?  For example, this works just fine.

```
%let x = %str( age format=best.);

proc sql;
    select &x. from sashelp.class;
quit;
```

Comment: The example is somewhat artificial; I'm aware of any number of workarounds, so what I'm really asking is WHY this error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason SAS doesn't like the "best." format.

i.e. when I try this, your code works

```
 %let x = %str(put(age, 8.));
```

????

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your code

```
%put _user_ ;
```

you will see how &x is quoted by %str, in the log. That is why the proc sql code doesn't work. Using %Unquote in the select portion of the proc sql statement will allow the code to run.

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/152-2007.pdf

Comment: this is really helpful-- thank you.  I think you need to use '%put' instead of 'put' though.